# How to use a template filter on a custom template tag?

Tags: django, templates, filter, tags

I have a django problem concerning template tags. I have a template tag named `modal_form` with 4 arguments. This template tag works perfectly with basic variables like:

```
{% modal_form "clients" contact_form "Contacts" "contact" %}
```

But it doesn't work when i try to filter a variable inside my custom template tag like:

```
{% modal_form "parameters" form_dict|key:parameter parameter name_dict|key:parameter %}
```

This custom filter works also perfectly outside the tag (this filter get the value of a dict at a specific key).
I have this error:

> Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key
>   [form_dict|key:parameter]

Maybe i have to write the tag in a different way to support filter inside ?

**This is my code for the tag:**

```
def modal_form(app, object_form, object_name, object_verbose_name):
    return { 'app': app, 'object_form': object_form, 'object_name': object_name, 'object_verbose_name': object_verbose_name }

register.inclusion_tag('tags/modal_form.html')(modal_form)
```

And my code for the filter:

```
def key(d, key_name):
    try:
        value = d[key_name]
    except KeyError:
        #from django.conf import settings

        #value = settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
        value = 0

    return value
key = register.filter('key', key)
```

Do you have any ideas ? Do you want more code ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: We can only help if you post your code; otherwise its just a guessing game.

Comment: Can you also share your custom tag and filter code

Comment: I have edited my post with codes, thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your tag and filter works fine separately, try to use [with statement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with var_one=form_dict|key:parameter var_two=name_dict|key:parameter %}
    {% modal_form "parameters" var_one parameter var_two %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: To add onto the above, the below allows you to set the result of a template tag use it in a filter.
`
{% with var='temp_tag arg1 arg2' %}
    {{var|filter_name: "Str"}}
{% endwith %}
`